# What is the use of beforeEach method in Kiwi/Quick test frameworks?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Why is `beforeEach` used in test frameworks like Kiwi and Quick?

```
beforeEach {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",
                bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))
            let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
            viewController = navigationController.topViewController as ViewController

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController = navigationController
            let _ = navigationController.view
            let _ = viewController.view
        }
```

Example code taken from: https://www.natashatherobot.com/unit-testing-in-swift-a-quick-look-at-quick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the equivalent of Apple's Test Framework `setUp` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctest/1500341-setup). It is executed before every test, to set up components and mocks that will be used in every test.

According to Kiwi's [wiki](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/wiki/Specs):

> beforeEach(aBlock) is run before every it block in all enclosed contexts. Code that actually sets up the particular context should go here.

It's helpful to avoid code repetition and that your tests have a standard setup among them.

In the piece of code that you shared, the `beforeEach` method is setting up a `UINavigationController` with a `rootViewController` extracted from the storyboard. It is also loading the view so the tests can access components such as outlets.